# Reallocate full Conda installation

Tags: python, anaconda, rpm, conda, rpmbuild

I want to create a tar.gz file with a complete Miniconda installation, including some packages to be able to distribute it to offline machines. This tar.gz will be installed with an RPM.

I've tried to pack everything doing:

```
sudo sh miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda
sudo /opt/miniconda/bin/conda create -p /opt/miniconda/envs --file packages.txt
tar -czf miniconda.tar.gz /opt/miniconda
```

Then I create a .spec file that extracts all the contents. This is the structure of rpmbuild directory:

```
[user@linux rpmbuild]$ tree -L 5
.
├── BUILD
├── BUILDROOT
├── RPMS
│   └── x86_64
│       └── foo-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
├── SOURCES
│   ├── foo-1.0
│   │   └── opt
│   │       └── miniconda
│   │           ├── bin
│   │           ├── conda-meta
│   │           ├── envs
│   │           ├── etc
│   │           ├── include
│   │           ├── lib
│   │           ├── LICENSE.txt
│   │           ├── pkgs
│   │           ├── share
│   │           └── ssl
│   └── foo-1.0.tar.gz
├── SPECS
│   └── foo.spec
└── SRPMS
    └── foo-1.0-1.src.rpm
```

.spec file

```
%define        __spec_install_post %{nil}
%define          debug_package %{nil}
%define        __os_install_post %{_dbpath}/brp-compress

Summary: Trying to distribute miniconda
Name: foo
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GPL+
Group: Development/Tools
SOURCE0 : %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root

%description
"Here's the description"

%prep
%setup -q

%build
# Nothing

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p  %{buildroot}
cp -a * %{buildroot}

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/opt/miniconda

%changelog
```

And when I try to install the rpm, it fails:

```
[user@linux rpmbuild]$ sudo yum localinstall ./RPMS/x86_64/foo-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for user: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Examining ./RPMS/x86_64/foo-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: foo-1.0-1.x86_64
Marking ./RPMS/x86_64/foo-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foo.x86_64 0:1.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python for package: foo-1.0-1.x86_64


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it.
Here's my .spec file

```
%define        __spec_install_post %{nil}
%define          debug_package %{nil}
%define        __os_install_post %{_dbpath}/brp-compress

%define tarversion foo-1.0
%define tarfile %{tarversion}.tar.gz
%define installscript install.sh

Summary: Trying to distribute miniconda
Name: foo
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GPL+
Group: Development/Tools
SOURCE1 : %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
SOURCE2 : %{installscript}
BuildRoot: %{_builddir}/%{name}-root

%description
%{summary}

%prep

%build
# Nothing

%install

mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
cp -a %{SOURCE1} %{SOURCE2} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/
chmod a+x %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/%{installscript}

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%{_bindir}/%{installscript}
%{_bindir}/%{tarfile}

%pre
echo "Deleting old miniconda installation..."
rm -rf /opt/miniconda

%preun
echo "Deleting old miniconda installation..."
rm -rf /opt/miniconda

%post
%{_bindir}/%{installscript}
rm -rf /tmp/dependencies
rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
rm /tmp/packages.txt

if [ -f /opt/miniconda/bin/python ]; then
    echo "Python is there!"
    echo "Checking version..."

    python_version="$(/opt/miniconda/bin/python --version)"
    if [[ "3.6.0" =~ "$python_version" ]]; then
        echo "Python version is correct: $python_version"
    else
        echo "ERROR: Python version is not correct"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Checking numpy version..."
    numpy_version="$(/opt/miniconda/envs/MyEnv/bin/python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)')"
    if [ "$numpy_version" == "1.12.1" ]; then
        echo "Numpy version is correct: $numpy_version"
    else
        echo "ERROR: Numpy version is not correct"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Checking scipy version..."
    scipy_version="$(/opt/miniconda/envs/MyEnv/bin/python -c 'import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)')"
    if [ "$scipy_version" == "0.19.0" ]; then
        echo "Scipy version is correct: $scipy_version"
    else
    echo "ERROR: Scipy version is not correct"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Checking scikit-learn version..."
    scikit_version="$(/opt/miniconda/envs/MyEnv/bin/python -c 'import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)')"
    if [ "$scikit_version" == "0.18.1" ]; then
        echo "Scikit-learn version is correct: $scikit_version"
    else
        echo "ERROR: scikit-learn version is not correct"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "ERROR: Miniconda Python installation was not found."
    exit 1
fi
```

This is the installation script.

```
[user@linux SOURCES]$ cat install.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Extracting dependencies..."
tar -zvxf /usr/bin/foo-1.0.tar.gz -C /tmp
echo "Installing Miniconda..."
sudo sh /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda
echo "Creating environment..."
sudo /opt/miniconda/bin/conda create -p /opt/miniconda/envs/MyEnv --file /tmp/packages.txt
```

And these are the dependencies of my project:

```
@EXPLICIT
file:///tmp/dependencies/libgfortran-3.0.0-1.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/mkl-2017.0.1-0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/numpy-1.12.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/openssl-1.0.2k-2.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/pip-9.0.1-py36_1.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/python-3.6.0-0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/readline-6.2-2.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/scikit-learn-0.18.1-np112py36_1.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/scipy-0.19.0-np112py36_0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/setuptools-27.2.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/sqlite-3.13.0-0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/tk-8.5.18-0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/wheel-0.29.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/xz-5.2.2-1.tar.bz2
file:///tmp/dependencies/zlib-1.2.8-3.tar.bz2
```